# Count per second on the log file

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

I have messages log file each line represents a cdr or transaction and that looks like:

```
2019-03-14 13:58:16,260 DEBUG xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

i have to calculate transactions per second. which means number of cdrs (lines) per seconds and generate report contains time and number of transactions (lines) something like:

```
     Time                    TPS
 2019-03-14 13:58:16        102
```

Comment: If that ',' is on every line, you could use: `cut -d',' -f1 | uniq -c`. If not, you should add other lines to the example input.

Comment: example of each line : `2019-03-14 00:07:01,688 DEBUG [org.mobicents.smsc.library.CdrGenerator] 2019-03-14 00:07:00,037 +0430,CCC,5,0,700566254,1,1,success,nsmsc_user,283308200,93702700006,412012105522548,null,Dear Customer, Only` ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
printf -- "    Time           TPS\n"

sed 's/,.*//' < inputfile |   # extract just the date-time
sort |
uniq -c |                     # field 1 is now the count of each line's occurrences
awk '{ print $2, $3, $1 }'    # rewrite as "date time count"
```